VBA - After copying and pasting range, range becomes invalid. Getting runtime error "method range of object worksheet failed"
When I add the sheet, the "range" becomes invalid... I'm not sure why this is happening.
I'm wanting to loop through a data set, and when a column value changes, create a new sheet and paste the values to that point in the new sheet. Right now with the code as it is it will do this once, but after the new sheet is created the range is all messed up.
     For i = 2 To lastrow
        If ws.Cells(i, 6) <> ws.Cells(i + 1, 6) Then
            ' add a new sheet then copy and paste to the new sheet
            'Set pastesheet = Sheets.Add
            ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(i, 20)).Copy
            Set pastesheet = Sheets.Add
            pastesheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            ws.Application.CutCopyMode = False
            pastesheet.Application.CutCopyMode = False

        End If
        
     Next

Right now with the code as it is it will do this once, but after the new sheet is created the range is all messed up.

Add the sheet before you copy.

Tried that, you can see I commented it out.

Or skip the copy/paste pastesheet.Range("A1").Resize(i,20).Value = ws.Range("A1").Resize(i,20).Value  Note that when you use Cells() with no worksheet qualifier, it will by default refer to the ActiveSheet, which may not be ws in your case

Tim Williams you are a scholar and a gentleman. Fixed it adding worksheet qualifier.
